# Filling a dataframe based on the column name and index value of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, dataframe_1, that looks like this:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5  ...  192
0   12  35  60  78  23  90      32
```

And another dataframe, dataframe_2, that looks like this:

```
    58   59   60    61   62 ... 350     
0   1    4    192   4    4      1
1   0    3    3     5    3      4
2   3    1    4     2    2      192
```

The values in dataframe_2 are the column names from dataframe_1. What I'd like to do is change the values in dataframe_2 based on the column names of dataframe_1, like so:

```
    58   59   60   61   62 ... 350     
0   35   23   32   23   23     35
1   12   78   78   90   78     23
2   78   35   23   60   60     32
```

I tried a for loop using .loc, but it did not work.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `replace`

```
d2.replace(dict(zip(d1.columns,d1.iloc[0])))
```

Answer (score 3):

### `stack` and `map`

```
# if necessary, cast,
# df1.columns = df1.columns.astype(int)

df2.stack().map(df1.iloc[0]).unstack()

   58  59  60  61  62  350
0  35  23  32  23  23   35
1  12  78  78  90  78   23
2  78  35  23  60  60   32
```

Stack `df2` so we can call `Series.map` to perform a single vectorised replacement using `df1`.

---

### `apply` and `map`

```
df2.apply(pd.Series.map, args=(df1.iloc[0],))

   58  59  60  61  62  350
0  35  23  32  23  23   35
1  12  78  78  90  78   23
2  78  35  23  60  60   32
```

Instead of stacking to get a Series, we apply a `map` operation across each column.

Answer (score 2):

You could define a dictionary from `df1` and use it to replace [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) the values in `df2`:

```
d = dict(zip(df1.columns, df1.values.ravel()))
df2.replace(d)

   58  59  60  61  62  350
0  35  23  32  23  23   35
1  12  78  78  90  78   23
2  78  35  23  60  60   32
```

---

Or stacking `df1` and then replacing:

```
df2.replace(df1.stack().droplevel(0))

   58  59  60  61  62  350
0  35  23  32  23  23   35
1  12  78  78  90  78   23
2  78  35  23  60  60   32
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a lookup table and map the values using the underlying `numpy array`.  This assumes integer column names.

```
u = np.zeros(df1.columns.max()+1, dtype=int)
u[df1.columns] = df1.iloc[0].values

u[df2.values]
```

```
array([[35, 23, 32, 23, 23, 35],
       [12, 78, 78, 90, 78, 23],
       [78, 35, 23, 60, 60, 32]])
```

---

If there are values that might not match a value in `df1`:

```
u = np.full(df1.columns.max()+1, np.nan)
u[df1.columns] = df1.iloc[0].values

u[df2.values]
```

And then `fillna` with `df2` if desired.

Answer (score 0):

```
df2.applymap(lambda x: df1.loc[0,x])
```